# iOS Facebook SDK 4.x read and publish permissions redundant logging in

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

I am upgrading the Facebook sdk from 3.x to 4.x and the Facebook docs make it clear that read permissions and publish permissions need to be requested separately. When the app requests read permissions, the user logs in and grants the permissions but when the app requests publish permissions, it makes the user log in again even though the user already has an access token? Is there a way to just request the permissions without having to force the user to log in again?

The Facebook android sdk allows this without having to log in twice but iOS seems to be preventing this behavior completely, which seems crazy. If an app implementation requires both read and publish permissions for the integration to even work, forcing the user to log in twice is just unnecessary friction and a bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the SDK class named `FBSDKInternalUtility.h,` in which we got one method

```
+ (BOOL)areAllPermissionsReadPermissions:(NSSet *)permissions
{
  for (NSString *permission in permissions) {
    if ([[self class] isPublishPermission:permission]) {
      return NO;
    }
  }
 return YES;
}

+ (BOOL)isPublishPermission:(NSString *)permission
{
 return [permission hasPrefix:@"publish"] ||
 [permission hasPrefix:@"manage"] ||
 [permission isEqualToString:@"ads_management"] ||
 [permission isEqualToString:@"create_event"] ||
 [permission isEqualToString:@"rsvp_event"];
}
```

They check below permission in both cases which, while passing permission as `NSSet` order are getting different, so below checks for first string and return NO. So What did is I have commented out few lines as mentioned below.

```
+ (BOOL)areAllPermissionsReadPermissions:(NSSet *)permissions
{
  //for (NSString *permission in permissions) {
   // if ([[self class] isPublishPermission:permission]) {
    //  return NO;
    // }
  //}
 return YES;
}
```

I not sure about the changes what I have done is valid or not, but I could have achieved what I wanted. So Happy. 
Please, let me know if you have any suggestion  to change.